# border-radius and overflow in opera browser

Tags: html, css, opera

I want to display a part of image in circle div. I have a code, but it doesn't work in Opera.

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: silver;
}
div {
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
      border: 1px solid;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 45px;
}
img {
      margin-left: -75px;
      width: 350px;
      height: 90px;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div>
      <img src="http://diskuse.jakpsatweb.cz/img/logo.png">
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpfEY/6/

How can I fix it?

Comment: here is a working hack (via transparent `:after` with overlaying border): http://jsfiddle.net/MWu2J/, but it does not look very pretty, so i'm not putting it as answer. Anyway, it looks like a bug in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Check border-radius support [hear](http://caniuse.com/border-radius) also check [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Looking at you code it seems working i have tested it on chrome, firefox and opera. and its working.

If you are using the older version try using

```
-webkit-border-radius: 45px;
-moz-border-radius: 45px;
border-radius: 45px;
```

**NOTE** But this is not required for morden browsers

Comment: I am using the latest version of Opera and its not working. It is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why an image would not respect the border-radius property. However I was able to get it to work using a background image.

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: silver;
}
div {
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
      border: 1px solid;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 45px;
      background:url(http://diskuse.jakpsatweb.cz/img/logo.png) -115px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpfEY/18/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want use a background image.